# How to threshold waiting time for VM in cloudsim

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, cloudsim

If we have 100 cloudlets and 10 VM, how to threshold waiting time for VM in cloudsim in order to move that cloudlet from one VM to another.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to migrate Cloudlets in CloudSim, despite there are some tags in CloudSimTags that imply it, the feature is not implemented at all.

In real environments, you don't migrate applications but VMs or containers. Migrating apps is not practical because you must find out which dependencies and configurations the app has.

CloudSim 4 has support to Container as a Service which is supposed to support container migration. But this version has a lot of reported and unfixed bugs and the project was last updated 3 years ago.

Anyway, if you want to use a modern, full-featured, state-of-the-art fork of CloudSim, try [CloudSim Plus](http://cloudsimplus.org). It doesn't provide container support, but it's an actively maintained project that fixed lots of bugs from CloudSim. It's completely documented and way easier to use.